# How to calculate rect-moving-in-a-curved-path collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, curves

I'm trying to find the best way to use collision detection for a rect moving in a curved path:
here is example of what i have 
[image]
I found few methods and I have hard time to find what is the best way.
I have the pure calculation method that is here:
http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/
and I also have the pixel perfect method that is here:
http://blog.muditjaju.infiniteeurekas.in/?p=1

I'm using cocos2d-x but it can be in any engine or language.  What is the best method for this?

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the rectangle leaves the path? Or are you trying to detect when the rectangle, which is moving on this path, collides with something else?

Answer (score 3):

Of the methods you listed, the pixel perfect is the only one which can solve your exact problem. That is, unless:

- The curved line is defined by an exact formula you can use in checking
- You create a series of boundary lines that Approximate the curved line, and check for the crossover of any vector.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: this is just example of the curved line the curved path can be longer 
with different shapes , so just use the pixel perfect method?

Comment: Yes, way more flexibility. The first method is only helpful for when the objects have 'hitboxes' or any mathematical basis for their collision areas.